# Will not install from thumb drive

Tags: system-installation, hardware

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my wife's laptop, Windows Vista had been removed by a previous owner. This was given to us. The previous owner said that the laptop should boot to Ubuntu without the USB that I have downloaded Ubuntu on to.

It says there is not enough memory to Install. I can't find out how to find out how much actual memory is left. I'm used to Windows and can find it easy. The hardrive should be pretty empy.

Any ideas?

Paul

Comment: You should be able to determine the amount of memory and other machine specifics from the BIOS screens. How you access BIOS depends on the machine - for some you hit the DEL key, others it is an F-key (F8). You might see a BIOS splash screen at boot up with instruction on how to enter BIOS.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the hard drive? You can do this from the Ubuntu live USB. Is there data on the hard drive that you need?

Comment: memory and storage space are 2 different things. the hard drive provides storage space. Memory (also referred to as RAM) is used by the system to process data that is currently being handled (like the stuff on your desk). The hard drive is more like a filing cabinet to store things that aren't needed right now but may be needed later. douggro is correct. The information you seek is in the BIOS. How to get there depends on the make and model of the system. Add that information to the question and we will be able to help you.